# jQuery Id of item being dragged

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, javascript, drag

This seems like it should be a simple task, but I'm a noob as far as goes jQuery, so here's what I'm looking for:

I have something like this:

```
<div class=draggable id=thing1> some contents </div>
<div class=draggable id=thing2> some other contents </div>
.
.
.
<div class=draggable id=thingN> content </div>
```

with this Javascript:

```
$(function() {
  $(".draggable").draggable();
  // from inside this block, how can I know the id of the thing I'm dragging?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `stop` callback, and access the `id` property of `this` (a reference to the element being dropped).

```
$(".draggable").draggable({
   stop: function() { alert(this.id);  }
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/8JKNv/).

Comment: Thank you. I forgot Javascript had `this`